# Texstudio and SVN

Tags: texstudio

I failed to use SVN with TexStudio.

My commands:

```
SVN: "C:/Program Files/SlikSvn/bin/svn.exe"

SVNADMIN: "C:/Program Files/SlikSvn/bin/svnadmin.exe"
```

When I try to check in my file, I get the following message:

> Process started: "C:/Program Files/SlikSvn/bin/svn.exe" ci -m "" "C:/Users/rustam/Documents/Thesis/beamer/presentation.tex"
>
> svn: E205005: The log message is a pathname (was -F intended?); use '--force-log' to override

Comment: How about giving it a non-empty comment? Ie -m x or something like that. You get the same error if you say -m xxx and xxx exists as a file in that directory.